# $\mathcal{A} = \{(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) \in R^{3} |x_{1} = x_{2} + x_{3}\}$ is a closed convex set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

If $\mathcal{A} = \{(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) \in R^{3} |x_{1} = x_{2} + x_{3}\}$,

How can I show this is a closed convex set ?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: The obvious answer would be you need to show it is closed, and you need to show it is convex...

Comment: I have a rough understanding of the concept. But not sure where to start with. Any guidance?

Comment: Yeah, write the definition of "convex" and see if the set satisfies it.

Comment: Hint: consider the function $z=f(x,y)=x+y$, as it is a plane, each condition shall get proved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*HINTS*

Let $t_n \in A$ where $t_n=(x_n,y_n,z_n) \to (x,y,z)$

> In $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the Euclideian metric, if $x_n=(x_n^{(1)},x_n^{(2)}...x_n^{d})$ and $x=(x_1,x_2...x_d)$,  then we  have that $x_n \to x$ iff $x_n^{(i)} \to x_i, \forall i=1,2...d$

We have that $$x_n \to x$$ $$y_n \to y$$ $$z_n \to z$$

Also $x_n \to x$ and $x_n=y_n+z_n \to y+z$ thus from the uniqueness of the limit of a sequence we have that $x=y+z$ so $(x,y,z) \in A$

Thus $A$ is closed.

For the convexity take $x,y \in A$ and $t \in (0,1)$ and prove that $tx+(1-t)y \in A$

Comment: Not sure how to proceed with the proof of closed set. I know what you wanted me to show is that the boundary also contains in A. So it becomes a closed set. But not sure how to do it mathematically.

Comment: @shani In a metric space a set $A$ is closed if   for every  sequence in $A$ which converges, its limit belongs to $A$

Comment: @shani i edited..you have the complete proof for closedness..The part of the convexity is not difficult,just calculations.

Comment: I was able to show that $x = y+z$. But after that I am bit lost. How can I say that $x, y, z \in A$ from that.

Comment: @Shani...The elements of the set $A$ have a property namely $:x=y+z$ for an arbitrary $(x,y,z) \in A$..we proved that the limit of the sequence has this property,so it belongs to $A$

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

First, $\mathcal{A}$ is closed, as it is the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$ under the continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$, $(x_1, x_2, x_3)\mapsto x_1-(x_2+x_3)$. Second, $\mathcal{A}$ is convex, because for $(x_1, x_2, x_3), (y_1, y_2, y_3)\in \mathcal{A}$, we have $t(x_1, x_2, x_3)+(1-t)(y_1, y_2, y_3)\in \mathcal{A}$ for all $t\in [0, 1]$, as $$tx_1+(1-t)y_1 = t(x_2+x_3)+(1-t)(y_2+y_3) = (tx_2+(1-t)y_2)+(tx_3+(1-t)y_3)$$

Comment: Thanks. I got the convex part done.

Comment: The topological argument for the closed part is super easy. A function is defined to be continuous iff the preimage of every open set is open (equivalently, the preimage of every closed set is closed), and $\mathcal{A}$ is by definition the preimage of $\{0\}$ under the map $f : (x_1, x_2, x_3)\mapsto x_1-(x_2+x_3)$.